# Why mysql request timeout when it can't find data?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

## Information

I have a `expressjs` server who use `sequelize` to connect to my db with some token to keep connection on. When the client send a existing token, the request get the token and let it go to next function but when the client send an empty or incorrect token, it blocks for few minutes and doesn't respond anymore.

## The request in the server part

```
const Token = require('./models/token');

function isAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies.token) {
        Token.findOne({where: {token: req.cookies.token}}).then(token => {
            console.log("TOKEN");
            if (!token) {
                console.log("2");
                res.clearCookie('token');
                res.redirect("/");
            } else
                next();
        })
    } else {
        console.log("1");
        res.redirect("/");
    }
};
```

When it's executed by the good token, it trigger the first `console.log` but with the invalid token, it doesn't trigger any of them but keep blocked.

## Model token

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

var Token = sequelize.define('token', {
    token: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    console.log('token table has been successfully created, if one doesn\'t exist');
}).catch(error => console.log('This error occured', error));

module.exports = Token;
```

I can't find another example on google, I found some thing but it doesn't link with my issue and even when I test them it still won't work.

## Update

It keep a long timeout when I modify the token to delete some char but when it's empty, the request doesn't have the issue.
I only send to db a 108 char code as a token and the db has only 15 entries.
When the request get 2 minutes, the browser cancel it and on the server it doesn't display any error.

### Server display

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `token`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `tokens` AS `token` WHERE `token`.`token` = 'token_invalid';
GET /api/loadUserCurrent - - ms - -
```

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when you send an invalid token? At the moment you seem to be trying to redirect what I presume to be an AJAX request.

Comment: @James From the client I send an axios request and I went to redirect the client on "/" and delete actual "token" cookie

Comment: Yeah so you can't redirect from an AJAX request, naturally (given this is an API) you would want to return an appropriate HTTP status e.g. 404, and then have the client do the redirecting on your behalf (you can still remove the cookie as part of the AJAX response).

Comment: @james Yes I have already change many things in my server to fix my issue (I don't know why it was fixed), I have move the Auth check at the start of the server.

Comment: Ok so is this a non-issue now then or do you still have a problem?

Comment: @James No, I have fixed the problem, but I don't know exactly what's the cause of it